# Switch_case для combobox в pyside

Tags: python, switch, combobox, case, pyside

Пытаюсь написать приложение на PySide, но столкнулся с проблемой: отсутствие стандартного оператора Switch_case в питоне. Нужно, что бы при выборе одного из вариантов в Combobox выполнялось несколько действий: другой Combobox заполнялся вариантами (т.е. разные варианты в первом combobox по разному заполняли второй), создалась переменная, которая хранит в себе определённое значение (опять же, зависит от того, что выбрать в combobox). 
Но реализовать это не могу уже несколько часов, скорее всего потому что, не совсем хорошо соображаю в классах.

Вот код:

```
class myClass(QWidget, main__uis.Ui_CD):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myClass, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        #connects
        self.AppCode_cbx.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updateUi)

        #start
        self.updateUi()

    def updateUi(self):
        #   if self.AppCode_cbx.currentIndex()== 0 : self.TCode_cbx.clear(), self.TCode_cbx.addItems(Code) 
        #   if self.AppCode_cbx.currentIndex()== 1 : self.TCode_cbx.clear(), self.TCode_cbx.addItems(tCode)`
```

Если использовать конструкцию с if (ныне закоментирована), то всё работает, но вариантов в combobox'ах очень много и через if это делать слишком громоздко и долго.
Подскажите, как реализовать здесь Switch_case?

Comment: Нет. Можно заменить ассоциативным массивом `dict`, но мне кажется для вашего случая это не подходит